# Practise to Load Spring Beans

Tags: spring, javabeans, loading, applicationcontext

Folks,

What's the recommended practise to load spring beans from ApplicationContext ? Do we write ServletContextListener to load this when server starts up takes And save bean info in the context?

Or write some static method to do:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-beans.xml");
```

And call this static method all the time?

Or write a public void method and call it all the time? In this case are spring beans initialized everytime? this looks too much of work by the container.

Please suggests, thanks.

Comment: It is all depending on the application.  If it is standalone you can use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext or FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.  If it is a web application you will use XmlWebApplicationContext.

Comment: All correct, but the web app ought to use the context loader listener for the app and not do it in application code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the context loader listener that's provided.  Configure it in the web.xml, as recommended.  You should neither think this much about it nor work this hard to load your beans.

Comment: See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create